# AVPlayer rotates portrait video to landscape

Tags: ios, rotation, orientation, avplayer, avasset

I am recording videos with AVcapture and playing them in an AVplayer.

```
    NSURL *videoUrl1 = [self.mediaInfo objectAtIndex:0];
AVURLAsset *videoAsset1 = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:videoUrl1 options:nil];
NSURL *videoUrl2 = [self.mediaInfo objectAtIndex:1];
AVURLAsset *videoAsset2 = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:videoUrl2 options:nil];
AVAssetTrack *videoTrack1 = [[videoAsset1 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]objectAtIndex:0];
AVAssetTrack *videoTrack2 = [[videoAsset2 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]objectAtIndex:0];
```

both tracks are put together:

```
     [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, video1) ofTrack:videoTrack1 atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
    [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, video2) ofTrack:videoTrack2 atTime:(compositionVideoTrack.timeRange.duration) error:nil];
```

and played:

```
    AVPlayerItem * newPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:self.composition];
//newPlayerItem.videoComposition = mainCompositionInst;
self.mediaPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:newPlayerItem];
self.playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.mediaPlayer];
[[self view].layer insertSublayer:self.playerLayer atIndex:0];
self.playerLayer.frame = [self view].layer.bounds;
self.playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill ;

[self playItem];
```

The strange thing is that the preferredTransform of the initial AVURLAsset is different from the AVAssetTrack for the exact same file:

AVURLASSET

txf.a = 1.000000 txf.b = 0.000000 txf.c = 0.000000 txf.d = 1.000000 txf.tx = 0.000000 txf.ty = 0.000000

AVAssetTrack

txf.a = 0.000000 txf.b = 1.000000 txf.c = -1.000000 txf.d = 0.000000 txf.tx = 480.000000 txf.ty = 0.000000

Any help to solve this rotation would be much appreciated, 
thanks in advance.

CL

Comment: I have same problem. Can you say me how you  resolved that?

Comment: It was quite hard to solve the issue, I suggest to read all this to understand how AVfoundation [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/AVFoundationPG.pdf)
Also, note that depending on the os and phone model you'll get different results, so in ly case i had to identify the phone model and apply the necessary transforms.good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Create video Composition

```
vidComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
```

set `vidComposition.instructions = mainInstruction (AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction)`
after edit video play with AVPlayer

Uncomment `newPlayerItem.videoComposition = mainCompositionInst;` and set vidComposition instead of mainCompositionInst.
`newPlayerItem.videoComposition = vidComposition;`

For editing video this tutorial might be help you. [raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-io‌​s](http://this%20tutorial%20might%20be%20help%20you.%20raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-io%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bs)

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have that problem too. Could you please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43292059/rotate-totally-landscape-view-when-movie-play-in-vlcplayer-with-swift-3/43314526?noredirect=1#comment73694186_43314526   ?

Comment: @MayPhyu , I have answered on your question. it might help you.